# Java Printf precision isn't rounding

Tags: java, formatting, printf, precision

I'm learning Java and trying to round numbers in a mock savings account to 2 decimal places using the printf(%.2f) feature. Trying it on it's own the feature works fine, but in my program it just doesn't seem to work. Here is the relevant code.

```
public void calculateMonthlyInterest() {
      double monthlyInterest = (annualInterestRate * savingsBalance)/12;
      savingsBalance = savingsBalance + monthlyInterest;
      System.out.printf("The new balance is $%.2f%n", savingsBalance);
}
```

It outputs without rounding the decimal places. Ex: "The new balance is $2006.6666666666667"

I don't understand why it works elsewhere, but not here?

I was suggested to give my input values, so here they are: annualInterestRate = .04, savingsBalance = 2000. After it runs through, the output is as listed above.

Comment: works for me - make sure you're running the code you think you're running?

Comment: You can rebuild and run the code. Also, it's will be better if you share your input values for the case.

Comment: Like the other two commentators here, I don't believe that this code produced the output you're describing.  Clear out your build directory, recompile your code, and try again.

Comment: @backdoor Rebuilding the code seemed to fix it for some reason, even though all I did was copy and pasted the same text into a new java file. Thanks, although I don't really understand what went wrong!